# Why did Bran come all this way?

Tags: game-of-thrones

In the final episode, Tyrion makes an impassioned speech about

> why Bran should become king,

To which Bran responds

> Why do you think I came all this way?

Or something like that, I don't remember the exact quote. But why would Bran say that? His power is to see the past, so he couldn't have known Tyrion was going to say that.

Comment: Why does everybody say that Bran cannot see the future?  He is the THREE Eyed Raven.  Why would the Raven have 3 eyes unless the eyes represent the past, present and future?

Comment: @krb Same reason that a third eye is a standard symbol of mysticism.  It simply denotes that you see *more* than people normally do; usually some form of "truth".  Doesn't have to mean you see one or more of the past/present/future any better than anyone else does, though it's a possibility.

Comment: For the Iron Throne! Now (SPOILERS) conveniently flat-packed, some re-assembly required.

Comment: The title is misleading. You're not asking for the reason for Bran going somewhere, you're asking why he says something about going somewhere.

Comment: He came all this way because: 1. He read the script. 2. Sansa and Arya wheeled him along - what was he gonna do? 3. It's damn cold up North in winter! Some sun to warm his aching broken bones. 4. Honestly I have no idea, it makes absolutely no sense.

Answer (score 11):

Bran always had some ability to see the future. Remember [Bran's vision](https://screenrant.com/game-thrones-bran-dragon-vision-kings-landing/) when he saw:

> shadow of a dragon flying over the King's landing

It came true in S8E5 when

> Danerys burned the city

Also the quote from GOT [fandom Wiki](https://gameofthrones.fandom.com/wiki/Bran_Stark)

> Skinchanging with a Heart tree, a Weirwood with a face carved in it by the Children of the Forest, allows Bran (when combined with his Greensight) to have vivid visions of past, present, and future events, including those far away from himself, though he is now capable of doing so without the need for skinchanging with a Heart tree. While in the visions, Bran is once again capable of walking.

Comment: I dont remember this vision, when was that?

Comment: When Bran was fleeing the Cave of the Three-Eyed Raven, he was being dragged by Meera while he was shown visions of the past, present, and future of Westeros. Updated my answer with the link for more details

Comment: Ah yes, a fan edited wiki is always an _excellent_ place to get unbiased and reliable information!

Comment: @Edlothiad, no its not but Bran did see Dragon shadow and it came true and his Warging powers only grew stronger after that.

Answer (score 8):

#### It doesn't matter. He doesn't need to see the future to have a goal and pursue it.

There has been a lot of discussion about what the bounds of Bran's powers are, and very little of it has been conclusively demonstrated in the show. I believe it has been suggested (by D&D commentary? I can't recall the exact reference) that Bran *can* perceive the future to some degree, though the precision and "fated-ness" of it is unclear.

But he could easily have come all the way to King's Landing to present himself as the best candidate for being king, even if he didn't really want the job, through a mundane analysis of the continent's political situation. That analysis could also have been sharpened by his supernatural grasp of history and knowledge of current events.

He's already said and done things to guide people into proper positions for his plans (or visions of the future, if you prefer) to work (like Arya, the Valyrian steel dagger, and the Night King).

**It is not necessary for Bran to have literally viewed these events in advance.**

It's also possible that his intentions were even more vague than that: he could have come to King's Landing to help end the wars and deaths that have plagued the world over the course of the show, and upon hearing Tyrion's speech he was convinced that accession was the best way to do that.

It could also be still less planned. Perhaps Bran is simply strengthening the story that Tyrion suggested would make him a king people could rally behind with another dramatic element, for the sake of the gathered council of lords and a future national legend.

#### The ultimate caveat

The worldbuilding of GoT is extensive, but less emphasized on the show than in the books. Opinions vary on how deep the issue runs, but there are plenty of instances of things not quite adding up on the show (powers described as working one way, but then arbitrarily working a different way seemingly for plot convenience, etc.).

We can always construct baroque explanations for why those things are consistent after all, but they frequently require assertions, varyingly supported by the source material, about how things work more broadly. And neither the show nor the books have purported to explain everything fully, leaving many mysteries where satisfying explanations may hide. This may well be an area in which no true canonical answer actually exists.

Comment: Agreed, it _could_ be that his powers are such that he knew what would happen, or it could also simply be that he deduced what would happen. It's not such a huge stretch, he knows the other potential candidates, he knows the kingdom is hugely war-weary and he would make a good anti-war compromise (given that everyone thinks he's incapable of fathering children). BloodRaven was incredibly politically knowledgable, perhaps this is a trait likely to be present in one who has unfettered access to people's pasts and secrets - if you know a person you can somewhat deduce how they will react.

Answer (score -1):

Is it possible that Bran, after connecting with the Night King, was used to position people and change people's behavior so that the Night King could rule through Bran?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  By stating this as a question, it's not clear if you're proposing this as an answer or asking a follow-up question.  Please read [answer]; answers are supposed to respond to the question.  If this *is* intended to be an answer, it should provide some in-universe evidence that the Night King was directing Bran.